# Exporting matrix with Logical indexing in Matlab

Tags: matlab, logical-operators

I trying to export logical 1 indices of a matrix to another variable without altering their position. Below I am trying to explain my doubt using a example:

```
l = logical([1 0 1 1 ;...
             1 1 1 0]);

A = [1 2 3 4;...
     5 6 7 8];

B = zeros(size(A));
B = A(l)
```

produces:

```
 B =

     1
     5
     6
     3
     7
     4
```

But what I am interested in getting is

```
B =

 1     0     3     4
 5     6     7     0
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = logical([1 0 1 1 ;...
             1 1 1 0]);

A = [1 2 3 4;...
     5 6 7 8];

A .* l % element-wise multiplication
```

no prob, you are welcome ;-) Accept, question closed! xD

---

**EDIT**

I'm afraid Stackoverflow became a page where everyone tries to beat other's answers by trying to make a longer and more detailed answer, even though not related to WHAT WAS ORIGINALLY ASKED. And not the one's which give a quick, easy, simple solution within a small amount of time, to exactly that SPECIFIC QUESTION. Suever immediately becomes an upvote by answering a question which was NOT asked, just because it is longer.

I'll also play the game and edit my answer: If you want to have other default options then 0, one could also adopt my solution and use:

```
~l*default_value + A.*l
```

I just want to say: It IS possible.

---

**EDIT2**

```
tic; 
for i = 1:1000000
  B = A.*l; 
end; 
toc
>> Elapsed time is 2.18214 seconds.

tic; 
for i = 1:1000000
  B=zeros(size(A)); 
  B(l)=A(l); 
end; 
toc
>>Elapsed time is 13.9691 seconds.
```

Choose for yourself.

---

**EDIT3** (Default value != 0)

```
>> tic; for i = 1:1e6; B = A.*l+100*(~l); end; toc
Elapsed time is 4.17261 seconds.
>> tic; for i = 1:1e6; B=100*ones(size(A)); B(l)=A(l); end; toc
Elapsed time is 14.2126 seconds.
```

Comment: Oooh god, how could I be so dumb. :( ... anyways thanks @tim :)

Comment: I'll accept the ans, but I usually allow people to respond.

Comment: @pkj: Dont forget it. No other answers will come anymore. So upvote+accept.

Answer (score 1):

While you could use @tim's approach for this specific example, a more general solution is to use the logical array to index both the thing you're retrieving values from *and* the array you're assigning into. This grabs the values in `A` at the `TRUE` locations in `I` and places them into the corresponding positions in `B`.

```
I = logical([1 0 1 1; 1 1 1 0]);
A = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8];

B = zeros(size(A));
B(I) = A(I);
```

The element-wise multiplication approach won't work if you want the "default" values in `B` to be anything other than 0. For example.

```
% Initialize B to an array of 100's
B = 100 * ones(size(A));

% Replace the elements specified by the logical array
B(I) = A(I);

%   1   100     3     4
%   5     6     7   100
```

Alternately, if you just want to zero-out the values in `A` you can also use logical indexing to do this.

```
A(~I) = 0;
```

As a sidenote, try to avoid using `l` for a variable name as it is very difficult to distinguish `l` from the number `1`.

Comment: here one must note that the declaration `B = zeros(size(A))` is required, else one would end up getting a vector. Thanks @Suever